# Azure AppService and Printing

Tags: azure, printing

Is is possible to print to an on premise printer from an Azure AppService or Azure Function?

I don't mean printing via the browser or user agent. I mean the server side code connects to a printer and sends the print output to a print queue.

Comment: If you are going to downvote, it would be nice to know why you feel this is an inappropriate question.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need connectivity to the printer. Assuming you don't want to expose the printer to the internet (don't do that), then you would need to have a virtual network that has connectivity back to your on-premises network (Express Route, VPN) and then join the web app to that virtual network using [regional vNet integration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet). Once you have done that then it will be down to the language you are using for your web app being able to work with the printer in question.

All of this ignores the potential security issues this could open up having an internet accessible application directly connecting to your on-premises network resources.